# Suppose that $a \mu = \mu a$ for all $a$ in $C^*$-algebra $A$. Then $\mu \in Z(A^{**})$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra and $\mu \in A^{**}$. Suppose that $a \mu = \mu a$ for all $a \in A$. Then $\mu \in Z(A^{**})$.

Comment: $\nu = \mu$????

Comment: If you are the same person who has been asking about the derivation problem for Cstar algebras (which, incidentally, **predates** the derivation problem for group algebras, and which was one of Johnson's main motivations for studying the derivation problem for group algebras) then I suggest you get your accounts merged. It does not help anyone if you have several anonymous accounts and it may create suspicions of sockpuppetry

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP is not engaging with the responses and has not clarified the context for their question

Answer (score 2):

I think this follows from the fact that multiplication in $A^{**}$ is separately weak-star continuous, i.e.

for all $a\in A^{**}$ the function $A^{**} \to A^{**}$, $b\mapsto ab$, is weak-star to weak-star continuous;

for all $a\in A^{**}$ the function $A^{**} \to A^{**}$, $b\mapsto ba$, is weak-star to weak-star continuous.

Therefore this should work for any Arens regular Banach algebra $A$.

Comment: For a Cstar algebra, appealing to Arens regularity may be seen as excessively abstract: just use results about von Neumann algebras (represented concretely on B(H) ) and the various topologies on them

Comment: why a $\in$ $A^*$?!

Comment: @user347731 Dear anonymous user, that was a typo. Apologies.